# ASP MVC routes: 3 routes for the same Action/View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have this controler with only 1 action and working with id(int):

```
public class PropertiesController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index (int idEstate = 0, int idCity = 0, int [] idNeighborhoods = null)
    {
        string IdEstate ;
        string IdCity ;
        int [] IdNeighborhoods ;

        #ReadOrSetCookie

        #SetViewBags

        #ReturnNeighborhoods

        #ReturnProperties

        return View();
    }
}
```

In the View I have a form, the user can select 1 state and 1 city and a set of neighborhoods. And when submitted returns to the Action Index that instead of reading this data a cookie will receive from the form, then search and return the properties. Working fine. I no have problens here.

My problem is on return displays for user the following url everytime:

> MySite/properties/index

And I need to return depending on what the user selects in the form If he just reported the state:

> MySite/properties/{StateInformed}

If he also selected a city:

> MySite/properties/{StateInformed}/{CityInformed}
>
> e.g. www.mysite.com/properties/Florida/Miami

My routConfig is the default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Properties", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And my simplified form is (I'm not reporting verb or anything different)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
   @Html.DropDownList("idEstado", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaEstados, "idEstado", "txtNomeEstado", ViewBag.idEstadoCookie))
   @Html.DropDownList("idCidade", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaCidades, "idCidade", "txtNomeCidade", ViewBag.idCidadeCookie))
   <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" />
}
```

Is possible do this with only 1 action and working with id (int)? Could someone help me do this?

**Update here -----------------------------------------**

Using the suggested here I try this...

I add this decoration in the controller:

```
    [Route("")]
    [Route("imoveis/{idEstado?}")]
    [Route("imoveis/{idEstado?}/{idCidade?}")]
    [Route("imoveis/{idEstado?}/{idCidade?}/{idRegiao?}")]
    public ActionResult Index (int idEstate = 0, int idCity = 0, int [] idNeighborhoods = null)
```

I change the form in view to using get and have a Id:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "imoveis", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "buscaimovel" }))
```

I add for each selct list in form the html atribut form. But in the select to State I put form = "buscaimovel" and for others I put a diferente form like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("idEstado", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaEstados, "idEstado", "txtNomeEstado", ViewBag.idEstadoCookie), new { @form = "buscaimovel" })
@Html.DropDownList("idCidade", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaCidades, "idCidade", "txtNomeCidade", ViewBag.idCidadeCookie), new { @form = "nulo" })
```

And finally I use a jquery to change the form attribute when an item is selected

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#idRegiao")
            .change(function () {
                if ($("#idRegiao").val() != null) $("#idRegiao").attr("form", "buscaimovel");
            });
    });
```

Nice! Now I have my diferent url return's:

> //localhost:57094/?idEstado=11
>
> //localhost:57094/?idEstado=11&idCidade=41
>
> //localhost:57094/?idEstado=11&idCidade=41&idRegiao=258

Or this:

> //localhost:57094/imoveis/11
>
> //localhost:57094/imoveis/11/41
>
> //localhost:57094/imoveis/11/41/258

**But see Is returned the id. Can I return the name of Estate, City and Region, by keeping my action with ids [int]?**

Comment: `return View();` will always return the same url. If you want a different url then you need to redirect in the POST method

Comment: I use the same view. But this view is make on the server to display different contents depending on what the user selected in the form (I use partial internal views)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Are you saying that I need to have different views to get different urls?

Comment: No. I said your have to redirect. Plus you need to define specific routes to achieve those url's

Comment: Thank you for the patience. I have years developing for desktop, but few months for web. I do not have much experience with routes. Then I need something like this: if (idState! = Null) redirecttoaction ("FindByState") elseif redirecttoaction ("FindbyEstateAndCity") ???

Comment: I think its time for you to start doing some research :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke lol of course Yes. I find this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/. And love the explanation. Now I had an idea to use javascript to change my form or button. So if the user selects a state the form requests controller / action / idestado. And if the user also select city request controller / action / idestado / idcidade. And finally I would decorate my action with [Route ("propertie / {estate?} / {City?}"]). That will work?

Comment: I add my new ideia in the question. Is working! But now I need hide the Id and show the names. Helps?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Attribute Routing

in route config:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Noe you can decorate you action with a route attribute
**Controller:**

```
        [Route("~/Prop/{StateInformed?}")]
        public ActionResult Test(string StateInformed = null)
        {
            // DO STAFF

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/Prop/{StateInformed?}")]
        public ActionResult Test(int? idState)
        {
            // DO STAFF

            String state = string.Empty;

            if (idState.HasValue)
            {
            state = "MyState";
            }

            // if state is null the route will be "/Prop" else "/Prop/MyState"
            return RedirectToAction("Test", new { StateInformed =state});
        }
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.TextBox("idState")
   <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" />
}
```

Examples [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Just play with it

Comment: I add my new ideia in the question. Is working! But now I need hide the Id and show the names. Helps?

Comment: I think your "new idea" is a new question. So make a new question

Answer (score 0):

you can either set properties that are not mandatory as optional or if you don't want to have these properties optional create separate method for each property combination.

Comment: You should add some samples to support your Answer.

Comment: Can you add a little more description about how you think this solves the question?  It's certainly not clear to me as it stands

Comment: "create separate method for each property combination" Then I ca'tdo this using just 1 action?

Comment: I add my new ideia in the question. Is working! But now I need hide the Id and show the names. Helps?

Comment: `[Route("imoveis/{idEstate?}/{idCity?}/{idNeighborhoods?}")]
public ActionResult Index (int idEstate = 0, int idCity = 0, int [] idNeighborhoods = null)`
be careful to have the same property names in route attribute as you have in the method.

Comment: @DavidSzorad can I use diferent names? I think the same name is nedded.

Comment: yes. I believe you will only need to have one method that will handle all those scenarios